# Framer motion Animate Presence exit issue

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, react-intersection-observer

I am having an issue with framer-motion AnimatePresence component. I am trying to start the animation after the component is visible within the viewport, to achieve this, I used react-intersection-observer. It works as intended for the starting animation, but the exit animation breaks and I am not sure what is causing the problem.
I created a sandbox that reproduces this behavior at https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-dream-rb5gu?file=/src/index.js

Comment: That's weird indeed, might be a bug, I see you already made an issue for framer https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/766

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like using the imperative [AnimationControls API](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animation/#animation-controls) is overriding the other declarative animation settings for the element (like `exit`).

Changing that `animate` prop to just accept a variant instead of an animation control seems to work:
[Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-roentgen-ey574?file=/src/App2.js)

I added a state for the current variant. Starts as `hidden` and updates to `visible` when `inView` changes:

```
// use variant instead of Animation Controls
const [variant, setVariant] = useState("hidden");

useEffect(() => {
  if (inView) {
    setVariant("visible");
  }
}, [inView]);
```

Then use that variant state to update the animation prop on the div:

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  {show && (
    <motion.div
      ref={ref}
      variants={containerVariants}
      initial="hidden"
      animate={variant} // use variant instead of Animation Controls
      exit="hidden"
    >
```